# MySQL to older MariaDB - slower performance

Tags: php, mysql, performance, mariadb

so I have a problem with DB migration from one webserver to another.
Server 1 has MySQL version 5.6 running under cPanel hosting...
Server 2 has MariaDB version 5.5 running under Webmin/Virtualmin
PHP version is the same on both of them...5.6

Anyway, I wanted to move a site from Server 1 to 2. I exported the DB using HeidiSQL and then imported the data on Server 2. The data imported fine, but the performance of the queries is worse by a factor of 10x. I went over the buffer size variables and all other "key" variables and they are the same or increased on Server 2.
I tried changing the storage engine from MyIsam to Aria or InnoDB but the results were the same...I also optimized the whole DB but again no luck. Indexes are the same on both servers.

I then decided to host the DB back on the original server and just load the files from the new one....I exported the new DB (only data using insert ignore) and imported that SQL back to Server 1. Immediately after the import the original DB started performing slowly as well...
Unless I use the original backup from when I moved the DB the first time, no matter how I update the DB to new data it starts performing poorly...

Example of query that takes 35 secs to run now when it used to take 3 secs:

```
select  p.*, pd.ID detailID,
        s.title subject, s.displayTitle, s.memberPanCode,
        s.virtualDelivery,
        CASE WHEN (DATE_ADD(p.releaseDate, INTERVAL 2 WEEK) > NOW()) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END pNew,
        CASE WHEN(s.publicChoice=1) THEN s.memberPanCode ELSE '' END usableSubject,
        CASE WHEN(s.displayTitle=1) THEN s.ID ELSE '0' END subjectID from  sProduct p
    inner join  sProductDetail pd  ON pd.ID_sProduct=p.ID
    left join  sProductDetailWarehouse pdw  ON pdw.ID_sProductDetail=pd.ID
    left join  sProductDetailSubjectPrice pdsp  ON pdsp.ID_sProductDetail=pd.ID
    left join  sSubject s  ON (s.memberPanCode=pdsp.memberPanCode
                          and  s.shownOnSite=1)
    where  (      s.publicChoice=1
              OR  s.defaultSubject=1
              OR  s.memberPanCode=''
              OR  s.memberPanCode IS NULL
           )
      AND  (      (pd.ID > 0  AND  s.displayTitle IS NOT NULL)
              OR  (pd.ID IS NULL  AND  s.displayTitle IS NULL )
              OR  (pd.ID > 0  and  p.ID_sSupplier > 0 )
              OR  (pd.ID > 0  and  pdsp.ID IS NULL )
              OR  (pd.ID > 0 and  s.displayTitle IS NULL )
           )
      AND  (DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) > p.showDate)
      AND  (      pdw.stock > 0
              OR  pd.stock > 0
              OR  (p.ID_sSupplier > 0  AND  p.ID_sSupplier <> '3')
           )
      and  p.published IN (1,2)
    GROUP BY  p.ID, s.memberPanCode
    order by  p.showDate desc
    limit  3
```

Explain statement for the new, slower DB:
[image]

Explain statement for the older, faster DB:
[image]

Any idea what is there left to check? What can I do to solve this?

Thank you for helping

Comment: what are the spec of the machines, what are the network interfaces(network problem?) 
I assume you are running under newest MariaDB ?

Comment: It's the same machine really, hardware spec is the same for both of them (to the tiniest detail). I'm running the newest MariaDB officially supported by Virtualmin, which is 5.5 sadly

Comment: There are a zillion possibilities.  To speed up the search...  If you have identified any query that seems to be slower, let's study it.  If not, turn on the slowlog with `long_query_time=0.2`, gather the results for a day, summarize via `pt-query-digest`, then let's look at the top couple of slow queries.  From that, we should be able to work backward to what the real cause is.

Comment: Added a slow query and the DB structure....thank you for helping

Comment: Please add `explain` statement results for both the cases

Comment: Added the explain statements as well...

Comment: I would suggest stopping using MariaDB 5 when it's on version 10 now. so your running miles out of date version and unsupported and as security flaws in it.

Comment: I would agree on that but unfortunately it's the latest version supported by Virtualmin/Webmin which is used for hosting purposes...

Comment: @Bostjan - please express your disapproval to that Host.

Comment: It looks like there is a different set of indexes on the two machines??

Comment: You also need to compare you configs: for example the buffer size for "Joins" doubled between 5.6 and 5.6 - given the complexity of the statement, you could be falling foul of this or one of the other changes in defaults: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_join_buffer_size . Check the full list: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-default-changes.html

Comment: @Bostjan https://www.virtualmin.com/node/45855

Comment: It seem you have different dataset in 2 DBs. Check Explain 1st row: **8768** vs **8809**. Another thing please share your both DBs schema for all 5 tables involved.

Comment: The question states "indexes are the same on both servers", but that appears to be erroneous. The first EXPLAIN output has references to some index names that are not found in the DDL (schema definition) script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How big are the tables?  InnoDB now does `FULLTEXT`.  MyISAM is being orphaned.  I agree with not using something as old as 5.5.  MariaDB has 10.0, 10.1, 10.2, 10.3.  MySQL has 5.6, 5.7, 8.0.  And there has been a lot of optimization work done in most of those.  By backtracking to 5.5, you probably lost some optimization features.  Alas, I have not spotted the specific thing that is lost.

The `ORs` are deadly for performance.  They essentially prevent the use of indexes.  I don't see any obvious way to rearrange things -- since the `ORs` are across multiple tables.

Here are some composite, covering, indexes that *might* help:

```
pd:   INDEX(ID_sProduct, ID, stock)  -- perhaps this order is best
pdw:  INDEX(ID_sProductDetail, stock)  -- in this  order
pdsp: INDEX(ID_sProductDetail, memberPanCode, ID)  -- in this order
s:    INDEX(memberPanCode, shownOnSite)  -- in either order
```

Also, add

```
p:  INDEX(showDate, published, ID, ID_sSupplier) -- in this order
```

and restructure the query by pulling `p.*` out of the main flow.  Currently the bulky p.* is hauled through the joins, etc before whittling down to only 3 rows.  By restructuring, we can find which 3 rows *first*, *then* fetch all the stuff:

```
SELECT p2.*, etc.
       p2.releaseDate > NOW() - INTERVAL 2 WEEK  AS pNew,
       etc.
    FROM (
        SELECT  toss p.*, add p.ID, keep other columns
            FROM ...
            LEFT JOIN ...
            ORDER BY...
            LIMIT 3
         ) AS x
    JOIN sProduct AS p2  ON x.ID = p2.ID
    ORDER BY p2.showDate desc
```

That new index is "covering" in that all the uses of `p` in the subquery are in the index.  I observed that `releaseDate` could be left out and picked up with the second use of `sProduct`.

I put `sShowDate` first in the index on the assumption that it does at least some filtering (`p.showDate < NOW + INTERVAL 1 DAY`).

The `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` combination necessitates one or two filesorts; they cannot be eliminated.  What I have done is minimize their cost by making them less bulky.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for taking the time to answer. I will most definitely be going over the queries and trying to optimize them. Your answer will most certainly point me to the right direction. I have to say though that the reason for starting this question was the difference between the two DB when it came to performance on the same set of data...I just can't figure out why one is so faster than the other.

Comment: @Bostjan - My Answer was a consolation prize for you -- I could not figure out the specific reason for the difference.  (The un-specific reason is that 5.5 is older, hence _possibly_ slower.)

Comment: Thank you :) it most certainly is a very big nudge in the right direction. There is just a feeling I have that I must be missing something trivial for such a difference to occur.

Comment: @Bostjan - glancing again at the `EXPLAINs`, I noticed that there might be an index on one machine that was not on the other.  I added a recommendation for `s`.

Comment: I'm awarding the bounty to this answer even though the problem still exists. It just seems to me there is something wrong/corrupt in the new DB

Comment: Just to let you know....the biggest difference came when I pulled the p.* out of the main flow like you suggested. With the added indexes, changing the engine to InnoDB it's now down to 3 secs again.

Answer (score 0):

This query is pretty rank, those `WHERE` conditions are needlessly complicated

Your original query (formatted)

```
   SELECT p.*,
          pd.ID,
          detailID, /** include table alias? */
          s.title subject,
          s.displayTitle,
          s.memberPanCode,
          s.virtualDelivery,
          (p.releaseDate < NOW() - INTERVAL 2 WEEK) pNew /** Booleans are resolve to 1/0 in MySQL */
          CASE WHEN s.publicChoice = 1 THEN s.memberPanCode ELSE '' END usableSubject,
          CASE WHEN s.displayTitle = 1 THEN s.ID ELSE '0' END subjectID 

     FROM sProduct p

     JOIN sProductDetail pd 
       ON pd.ID_sProduct = p.ID

LEFT JOIN sProductDetailWarehouse pdw 
       ON pdw.ID_sProductDetail = pd.ID

LEFT JOIN sProductDetailSubjectPrice pdsp 
       ON pdsp.ID_sProductDetail = pd.ID 

LEFT JOIN sSubject s 
       ON s.memberPanCode = pdsp.memberPanCode 
      AND s.shownOnSite=1

    WHERE (s.publicChoice=1 OR s.defaultSubject=1 OR s.memberPanCode='' OR s.memberPanCode IS NULL)  
      AND /** (
            (pd.ID > 0 AND s.displayTitle IS NOT NULL)
         OR (pd.ID IS NULL AND s.displayTitle IS NULL) 
         OR (pd.ID > 0 AND p.ID_sSupplier > 0) 
         OR (pd.ID > 0 AND pdsp.ID IS NULL) 
         OR (pd.ID > 0 AND s.displayTitle IS NULL)
          ) */ pd.ID > 0 /** see below */
      AND p.showDate < NOW() + INTERVAL 1 DAY 
      AND (pdw.stock > 0 OR pd.stock > 0 OR (p.ID_sSupplier > 0 AND p.ID_sSupplier <> '3'))  
      AND p.published IN (1,2)

 GROUP BY p.ID, s.memberPanCode 
 ORDER BY p.showDate DESC 
    LIMIT 3
```

Let's start with this condition

```
  AND (
         /** This with the last subcondition is just pd.ID > 0 */
         (pd.ID > 0 AND s.displayTitle IS NOT NULL)  

         /** This is impossible due to your INNER JOIN */
      OR (pd.ID IS NULL AND s.displayTitle IS NULL)

      OR (pd.ID > 0 AND p.ID_sSupplier > 0) 
      OR (pd.ID > 0 AND pdsp.ID IS NULL) 

         /** This with the first subcondition is just pd.ID > 0 */
      OR (pd.ID > 0 AND s.displayTitle IS NULL)
       )
```

**That whole condition resolves to `pd.ID > 0`**, which is always TRUE unless you have manually added a product with ID of 0

I suspect `(p.ID_sSupplier > 0 AND p.ID_sSupplier <> '3')` can become just `p.ID_sSupplier <> 3` for the same reason

This first condition seems super inclusive too

```
WHERE (
      s.publicChoice=1 
     OR s.defaultSubject=1 
     OR s.memberPanCode='' 
     OR s.memberPanCode IS NULL
      )  
   ...
```

Which leads me to question which rows you are actually trying to avoid with this condition?

That GROUP BY clause is worrisome too, as you have no aggregate columns selected.. a lot of your final columns will be arbitrarily selected

What are you actually trying to achieve with this query?

It's worth remembering that `OR` conditions tend to be slower to resolve than `AND` conditions when using queries

Comment: Hi, thank you as well for posting this well thought out answer. I agree the query is a mess as is most of the site...I took over the maintenance of it when it moved servers...I will be optimizing most queries, but like I said in the above answer, I was baffled by the difference between the two DBs. Thank you so much though for the effort.

Comment: No problem, happy to help! I understand the bafflement, although it looks like you have some other answers/comments that point towards what may have happened. Although it is interesting from an academic point of view.. if you are optimising the queries anyway, you'll probably end up with a wildly different explain plan on both servers, so an exact answer to the question may end up obsolete!

Answer (score 0):

The execution plans (show in the EXPLAIN output) are different. So we reasonably expect different performance characteristics.

As @RickJames pointed out in a comment, there seem to be some **indexes missing** in the target environment.

The question states:  "Indexes are the same on both servers."

But the information provided leads us to a conclusion that the indexs are *not* the same.

We see some indexes referenced in the output of the first EXPLAIN. And those index names are not found in the output of the second EXPLAIN. Those index names are also not found in the schema definition script.

---

Q: Why are some of the indexes (reported in the first EXPLAIN missing) from the schema definition?

Q: Was the output from `mysqldump` file for the migration modified to remove some index definitions?

Q: Was some tool other than `mysqldump` used to extract the schema definition for the migration, and were the indexes were omitted?

Q: Did some "create index" statements fail to execute in the target environment? (Possibly because of limits on sizes of columns in indexes?)

---

Or maybe I have it the other way around, maybe there are indexes that were added in the target that didn't exist in the source.

Comment: Hi, yes...there were indexes added in the new, slower environment...I used both HeidiSQL and mysqldump to create DB backups, but both deliver the same abysmal performance